# Find the volume $V$ of the described solid $S$.

Tags: calculus

Find the volume $V$ of the described solid $S$.

The base of $S$ is the triangular region with vertices 
$(0, 0), (4,0)$, and $(0, 4)$.Cross-sections perpendicular to the x−axis are squares.

My answer is $V = 2π\left(\frac{27}{2} - \frac{27}{5}\right) = \left(\frac{π}{5} \right)(135 - 54) = \frac{81π}{5} $

Comment: Your values are way off!

Comment: Where did that $\pi$ come from?

Comment: I think I have the wrong formula. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description of the solid, the base of the square in the plane perpendicular to the $x$-axis goes from the $x$-axis to the line $y=4-x$, so the side length is $4-x$. The area of that square is, of course, $y^2$, and the values of $x$ for those perpendicular planes run from $0$ to $4$.

Therefore the volume you want is

$$\int_0^4 (4-x)^2\,dx$$

You can finish from here.